# Override a css proprty for a child element

Tags: html, css

I have a html block like:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul class="sidebar-menu">
        {% for name in name_list %}
            {% if name == 'abc' %}
                <li class="sub-menu special">...</li>
            {% else %}
                <li class="sub-menu">...</li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

The css for this block is:

```
#sidebar {
    width: 210px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: #EFF0F6;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Now i want to override the background color for list element with class `special` to black. But i am not able to override it. How to do that?

> Note: The templating language is django's templating language.

Comment: could you make the question clearer? what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @JacobGray Currently for each list item the background color is #EFF0F6. I want to change the color to black for each item where class `special is added`

Comment: Did Mike C's answer work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a more specific selector:

```
#sidebar .special {
  background: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
ul.sidebar-menu li.special{background-color:#000000}
```

Comment: You should really avoid using `!important` when you don't have to. It makes it much harder to style other things in the future.

Comment: He said he need to override the style thats why important used.

Comment: But you only need to use `!important` if a more specific selector is preventing you from applying the style. If the same selector appears twice on the page, the last one seen will be used. `!important` basically resets the whole specificity chain and makes things really difficult in the long run.

Comment: @satya Mike C is correct, `!important` should only be used where a more specific selector won't work, such as in overriding inline styles